# Usar funcion CONVERT de SQL en consulta con INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server

Quiero hacer una consulta entre dos tablas para saber si las fechas son iguales, las cuales tengo en formato yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:SS.SSS.
Si hago esta consulta todo esta bien mientras todos los datos se correspondan:

```
SELECT*
  FROM Agenda_Reuniones
  inner join Agenda_MasterSchedules on Agenda_Reuniones.FechaHoraInicio = Agenda_MasterSchedules.Fecha
```

pero lo que yo quiero es que solo se tenga en cuenta la fecha (descartando la hora) lo cual se logra con lo siguiente:

```
convert(datetime, floor(convert(float, FechaHoraInicio)))
```

lo cual me proporciona resultados correctos si la consulta es contra una fecha harcodeada como:

```
SELECT*
  FROM Agenda_Reuniones
where convert(datetime, floor(convert(float, FechaHoraInicio))) = '2023-05-08'
```

pero al querer usarlo en INNER JOIN de esta forma da error:

```
SELECT*
  FROM Agenda_Reuniones
  inner join Agenda_MasterSchedules on Agenda_Reuniones.convert(datetime, floor(convert(float, FechaHoraInicio))) = Agenda_MasterSchedules.convert(datetime, floor(convert(float, Fecha)))
```

de seguro hay una forma, agradezco cualquier ayuda!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es un simple error de sintaxis que me parece que viene de otro lenguaje de programación. Tomaste la tabla como objeto y `CONVERT` como si fuera un método de ese objeto.

En las tablas de SQL Server no se tiene ese concepto. Las tablas no tienen métodos. En su lugar, las funciones existen como objetos independientes y pueden ser del sistema (como en este caso) o definidas por el usuario.

Otro punto, es que tomaste la opción más complicada para eliminar el tiempo de la fecha. Es mucho más fácil convertirlo a `date`.

```
SELECT *
  FROM Agenda_Reuniones             AS ar
  INNER JOIN Agenda_MasterSchedules AS ams ON CONVERT(date, ar.FechaHoraInicio) = CONVERT(date, ams.Fecha);
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias!! y por el convertirlo a date tambien!!